# How to loop through all the contents in a directory using a positional parameter inside of a for... in loop?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to display the contents of any directory that a user gives me and I'm trying to echo that the contents inside of the directory are either a file or a directory using a for... in loop. The variable called dir which is equal to argument $1 won't accept the variable inside of my for loop. I get an error that says $dir is not a valid identifier. I was just wondering what I suppose to put their so it can go over the users directory to see if they are files or directories. I hope what I'm saying makes sense.

```
#!/bin/bash

dir=$1

for $dir in *
    do
        if [[ -d "$dir" ]]; then
            echo "$dir is a directory"

        elif [[ -f "$dir" ]]; then
            echo "$dir is a file"
    fi
done
```

Comment: I think you're looking for `for file in "$dir"/*` ... `[[ -d $file ]]` ...

Comment: I agree with the comment above. Syntax is: "for variable in pattern" and variable cannot have a $ in front of it. This is the variable on which the loop is performed.

Comment: @oguz ismail It ended up working but I was just wondering what the "file" part does in the for loop. I know that it represents the loop-index but I don't know what that term means. I was just wondering if you could explain it.

Comment: I also don't know if I used the @ symbol correctly when I was trying to ask oguz ismail a question.

Comment: We call it the loop's *control variable*. `"$dir"/*` expands to pathnames, and the loop body is executed for each with the variable `file` is assigned the current pathname. Yes, you did use it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Here you don't iterate over the content of the $dir repertory.

The use of the for loop here

do

```sh
# here you build a correct path from where the script is run 
dir="${PWD}/$1"

# here you can test if the rep passed in args exist ifnot, exit 
[[ ! -e "$dir" ]] && exit 0 

for cursor in $dir/*; do 
   if [[ -d "$cursor" ]]; then
      echo "$cursor is a directory"
   elif [[ -f "$cursor" ]]; then
      echo "$cursor is a file"
   fi 
done
```

Answer (score 0):

What you've got so far is close. A good way to do it might be to use the current directory, if the user doesn't provide one.

Before using a glob pattern, you should first check that what the user provided *is* a directory. Also remember that there are files which are neither directories or regular files.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# -lt 1 ]]; then
    target=./
else
    target=$1
fi

[[ -e "$target" ]] || { echo "$1: Does not exist" >&2; exit 1; }
[[ -d "$target" ]] || { echo "$1: Not a directory" >&2; exit 1; }
[[ -r "$target" ]] || { echo "$1: No read permission" >&2; exit 1; }

if [[ $# -lt 1 ]]; then
    target=
else
    # User may or may not give a trailing slash, so guarantee one.
    target=${target%/}/
fi

for i in "$target"*; do
    if [[ -d "$i" ]]; then
        echo "$i is a directory"
    elif [[ -f "$i" ]]; then
        echo "$i is a file"
    else
        echo "$i is not a directory or regular file"
    fi
done
```